# Why is this component that looks like a capacitor with ground lines in this circuit diagram different from a polarized capacitor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, components

What is the component that is represented with two horizontal lines like a capacitor with three Ground Chassis lines connecting them and a + at the top and a 10μ label.

See picture below (top right corner):

[image]

Comment: @A.Lacasse if it's an electrolytic capacitor, why does it look different from the 2.2uF capacitor at the bottom right of the diagram?

Comment: @A.Lacasse wait, what is the 2.2uF capacitor then?

Comment: It's probably an other type of polarized capacitor. It might be a tantalum capacitor.

Comment: @A.Lacasse It's worth noting that tantalum capacitors are _also_ electrolytic capacitors. The common type you're probably thinking of is properly called an aluminum electrolytic capacitor, in contrast to tantalum electrolytic or niobium electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: @Hearth Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It's an electrolytic capacitor, but they used two different symbols for electrolytic capacitors (10\$\mu\$ and 2.2\$\mu\$) for some reason. Perhaps one or the other was added at a later date.

Note that the [datasheet](https://www.voti.nl/docs/M51660L.pdf) also (in print) recommends 10\$\mu\$F connected to pin 13.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the 10 µF is aluminium electrolytic and the 2.2 µF is tantlum.

Comment: @pipe nothing in the datasheet indicates it, but that would certainly be appropriate (size considerations, and you wouldn’t want a tantalum across the power supply). I’m not aware of a good convention that would use the different symbols like that.